# How to write json endpoints for autocomplete?

Tags: amp-html, autosuggest

I am trying to apply AMP Autosuggest (https://ampbyexample.com/advanced/autosuggest/) to my website.

How can i prepare endpoints to form (action-xhr) and list (src)?

```
  <form method="post"
  action-xhr="https://ampbyexample.com/advanced/autosuggest/address"
  target="_blank"
  id="search-form"
  on="
  submit: autosuggest-list.hide;
  submit-success: autosuggest-list.hide;
  submit-error: autosuggest-list.hide">


   <amp-list class="autosuggest-box"
   layout="fixed-height"
   height="120"
   src="/advanced/autosuggest/search_list"
   [src]="query ?
   autosuggest.endpoint + query :
   autosuggest.emptyAndInitialTemplateJson"
   id="autosuggest-list">
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to write a custom API endpoint or use an API endpoint that already exists? The former has very little to do with AMP and will likely need to question posted elsewhere.

Either way, using an endpoint requires setting the `amp-state` for the specific form/element to use autosuggest.

```
<amp-state id="autosuggest">
    <script type="application/json">
    {
        "endpoint": "/advanced/autosuggest/search_list?q=",
        "emptyAndInitialTemplateJson": [{
            "query": "",
            "results": []
        }]
    }
    </script>
</amp-state>
```